# Batch rename file by substring the filename

Tags: linux, command-line, rename

I have files

```
..
00016_0912RP10R6_RampMotorway9_0912RP10R6_13.646852_100.687103.jpg
00017_0912RP10R6_RampMotorway9_0912RP10R6_13.646956_100.686897.jpg
00018_0912RP10R6_RampMotorway9_0912RP10R6_13.647067_100.686684.jpg
...
```

I would like to have

```
00016.jpg
00017.jpg
00018.jpg
```

What is the best linux command to loop through subfolders and rename it ?

Comment: Look into using find and awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `find`:

```
find . -type f -name '*_*.jpg' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        newname=${pathname##*/}
        newname="${pathname%/*}/${newname%%_*}.jpg"
        printf "Would move %s to %s\n" "$pathname" "$newname"
        # mv -i "$pathname" "$newname"
    done' sh {} +
```

This would find the pathnames all regular files in or below the current directory whose names match the given pattern.  For batches of these pathnames, a short shell script is executed that loops over the given pathnames and renames the files (the actual renaming is commented out for safety).

Given a pathname like `./a/b/c/foo0_some_other_bits.jpg`, the shell script would transform this into `./a/b/c/foo0.jpg` by first deleting the directories (producing `foo0_some_other_bits.jpg`) and then deleting everything after the first `_` character and adding the directories back again. The directory bit of the pathname is deleted and replaced just in case it also happens to contain one or several `_` characters. This is done using standard parameter expansions.

Using the `globstar` shell option in `bash`:

```
shopt -s globstar   # use "set -o globstar" in ksh93, or remove completely in zsh
for pathname in ./**/*.jpg; do
    [ -f "$pathname" ] || continue
    newname=${pathname##*/}
    newname="${pathname%/*}/${newname%%_*}.jpg"
    printf "Would move %s to %s\n" "$pathname" "$newname"
    # mv -i "$pathname" "$newname"
done
```

This is exactly equivalent to the above `find` command, with the only difference that it wouldn't find hidden names (add `shopt -s dotglob` for that).

Answer (score 0):

Simple way using parameter substitution in `bash`:

```
for file in *.jpg; do mv "${file}" "${file/_*/.jpg}";done
```

That will loop trough the files if run in the directory they are in.

Answer (score 0):

```
pax -rw -'s/_[^/]*\.jpg/.jpg/' -'s/.*//' . .
```

might work.

Comment: `pax -rwl's/_[^/]*\.jpg$/.jpg'/ -s/.\*// . .` could be better with hardlinking the `-s`ubstitution results, i think. its been awhile, though.